# The ';' <right arrow> key doesn't seem to work in normal mode

Tags: vim

I am new to VIM and I need help in fixing an odd problem.  I recently encountered an issue with the ';'  key in normal mode.  The key works fine normally, but will not act as the right arrow key in normal mode.  I have not mucked with any settings (as far as I know) and it seems to be the only key with this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `;` command in normal mode repeats the latest jump from `f` / `t` / `F` / `T`, as [`:help ;`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3B) will tell you. If you haven't done such a jump, or if there's no such character in the line, the command will *beep* instead.

The "right arrow" you're referring to sounds like the `l` command, moving character by character to the right. It's right next to the `;` key on many keyboards. You might have mixed that up. All *vi* character motions are on the right hand's home row, but it's `h` / `j` / `k` / `l`, so one to the left from the natural resting position of the fingers (for historical reasons).

#### troubleshooting tips

- Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove to be a very powerful and efficient editor.
- If you suspect any misconfiguration, you can launch Vim with the [`--clean`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--clean) argument to temporarily turn any customization off.
- The `:map` command (and its various variants) can show you what got mapped. With a `:verbose` tacked in front, it'll also show you *where* the map got defined.

Comment: Ingo, thanks much. When I said I was new I guess it became painfully obvious. My mind had mapped a different keyboard than VIM.  Thanks for you patience and assistance!

Comment: Don't worry, some questions appear trivial in retrospect, but are still worthwhile to ask. I've added generic tips in my answer to make this apply to other, similar situations.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.